# Is there a way to automatically run a macro upon opening Excel files with similar file names?

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have researched a good amount and tried this on my own this afternoon but was unsuccessful. When users download and open .XLS files that begin with "Current Approved", I want a macro to automatically run from my "PERSONAL.XLSB" file on any "Current Approved*.XLS" file upon opening it (* is a Wildcard). That way I can just put the code in any given users "PERSONAL.XLSB" file one time, and the macro will just automatically be triggered without the user needing to remember to trigger the macro via a shortcut key or button.

From my research [here](https://exceloffthegrid.com/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook/) and in other places, I have only seen ways to:

1. Run the macro when opening the workbook which contains the macro.
2. Run a macro when any workbook is opened.

I have tried to modify #2 from the link above, but I've NOT figured out how to automatically run macros in this manner on files with similar names.

```
'Declare the application event variable
Public WithEvents MonitorApp As Application

'Set the event variable be the Excel Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set MonitorApp = Application
End Sub

'This Macro will run whenever an Excel Workbooks is opened
Private Sub MonitorApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook

    For Each Wb2 In Workbooks
        If Wb2.Name Like "Current Approved*" Then
            Wb2.Activate
            MsgBox "Test"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Essentially, if I download an excel file from our CRM that begins with "Current Approved" and open it, I would like to see a messagebox of "Test".

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine! Please note that in order for it to work, two conditions need to be met: 1) The workbook that has the macro must be open. 2) The workbook that has the macro must be closed and re-opened after the code is initially added in order for the `MonitorApp` variable to be set.

Comment: Actually... Excel just crashed on me and when it reopened... the code worked and I got dozens of "Test" message boxes open up. So, it actually works! Thanks for the comment @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: You're getting multiple because your code is checking all workbooks. See my answer below that will only check the OPENED workbook.

Comment: PGCodeRider is right. In addition to what I mentioned above, you should indeed use the `Wb` parameter instead of iterating all the open workbooks @DavidErickson

Comment: @PGCodeRider The code in my original post is working for me. To alleviate confusion from my comment, the reason why  I got lots of messages because I had lots of different files with  "Current Approved*" open, so when Excel reopened, it automatically crashed and reopened all those files, hence all of the notifications notifications. Now when I open one of those files, I get ONE notification.

Comment: @DavidErickson That's right! However, every time you open a workbook that starts with "Current Approved", you'll get a message box _for each open workbook that starts with the same string_, which, I assume, is _Not_ what you want. Using the `Wb` variable will only execute the code for the last-opened workbook _(that matches the criteria)_ even if you have a dozen more workbooks open _that also match the criteria_.

Comment: @DavidErickson I realize that. Is that good? Based on your coding it seems your objeective is to ONLY test a file that's opened. Not more than one. Your code is currently set to test all OPENED workbooks. Would this confuse your users if they had two files also open that met this criteria? Obviously it's your code, I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed since he's checking the file name, it can't possibly be useful to check all of them. By opening, they'll be checked. No need to check more, but it could generate redundant alerts.... who knows... I'll give you a tick anyway! 

Comment: You guys are both right.. I see what you mean and reproduced after testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't look like what you're describing. The below code should display the "Test" `MsgBox` when opening workbooks meeting the rule of starting with "Current Approved"

```
'This Macro will run whenever an Excel Workbooks is opened
Private Sub MonitorApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Const cText As String = "Current Approved"

    If UCase(Left(Wb.Name, Len(cText))) = UCase(cText) Then
           ' Wb2.Activate
            MsgBox "Test"
    End If

End Sub
```